# Wordpress Theme: replace logo image with title site if file doesn´t exist on server

Tags: images, themes

I'm trying to make a theme that picks an image from a folder based on the domain name, and if the file does not exist, then place a H3 with the site's title.

My code is:

```
<?php $server_name = preg_replace('/([wW]{3,3}\.|)\.(es|com|net)/', '',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); $imagen = bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/logos/'.$server_name.'.png'; if (file_exists(get_template_directory(). '/images/logos/' .$server_name.'.png')) { ?>
   <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $imagen ?>" border="0" width="230px" height="60px" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"/></a>
  <?php  }else{ ?>
<h3><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h3>
  <?php } ?>
```

When I tested it on a responsive theme like:

```
 <?php if (file_exists(get_template_directory(). '/core/images/logos/'.$nombre_servidor = preg_replace('/([wW]{3,3}\.|)\.(es|com|net)/', '',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'.png')){ ?>
   <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"/></a>
  <?php  }else{ ?>
<h3><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h3>
  <?php } ?>
```

it works like a charm, but I cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: so what I have to do to change to that category... ? :)

Comment: "works like a charm" implies it does work, so what exactly is the issue that you are having?

Comment: the first code that I post give me the URL with the www. before, not lile the second one. And the second one did not work at all in the other theme.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
<?php if (file_exists(get_template_directory().'/images/logos/'.$server_name = preg_replace('/[wW]{3,3}\.|\.(es|com|net)/', '',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'.png')) { ?>
   <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/logos/<?php echo $server_name = preg_replace('/[wW]{3,3}\.|\.(es|com|net)/', '',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'.png' ?>" border="0" width="230px" height="60px" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"/></a>
  <?php  }else{ ?>
<h3><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h3>
  <?php } ?>
```

Thanks at all!